# Java Object within Dataset being output as {} in Spark streaming when writing out as JSON, how can I get the actual value?

Tags: json, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I have a Java object that is structured like the following:

```
public class Example{
  private String key;
  private Object value;

  getters and setters here...
}
```

key stores the type of the object so string or long as a string. value stores the actual value of the object.

I have a dataset/dataframe containing Example and when I output it in json in this manner `df.writeStream.format("json").output.option("path", "mypath").start().awaitTermination()` the JSON will come out in two ways.

1. Object is null so Spark does not output it.
   `{key:"string"}` or `{key:"long"}`
2. Object is not null so Spark does output it, but only as {}.
   `{key:"string", value:{}}` or `{key:"long", value:{}}`

I need the JSON output to include the actual value, but because it is declared as an object I am guessing spark cannot interpret it well. I need it to output like this: `{key:"string", value:"abc"}` or `{key:"long", value:12345}`

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!